# SQL Server : DATEADD() not working beyond milliseconds when using a string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

Does anyone know why something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,4,'2021-11-01 05:10:00.0000000')
```

returns the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But when using only up to *milliseconds* like

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 4, '2021-11-01 05:10:00.000')
```

it works and returns:

```
2021-11-01 13:10:00.000
```

And when using it in a table where the column includes the *nanosecond* like

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 4, column-name)
```

it also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you've supplied a literal string, and so `DATEADD` converts the value to it's default data type, `datetime`. A `datetime` is accurate to 1/300th of a second and a value like `2021-11-01 05:10:00.0000000` therefore is too large; it has an accuracy greater than 1/300th of a second.

If you explicitly converted the value to a date and time data type that goes up to 1/1000000 of a second, it would work:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,4,CONVERT(datetime2(7),'2021-11-01 05:10:00.0000000'))
```

Comment: So why does it work with tables even if it has _nanoseconds_

Comment: Because the column isn't a `varchar`, @Shmiel ... It's likely a `datetime2`.

Comment: For erxample, @Shmiel, note that in this fiddle, the error is replicated with a column *if* you made the poor design choice of storing date and time values in a `varchar`: [db<>fidd;e](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de9ec6f3078d547cb4427ebd5ef3eeaa)

Answer (score 3):

From the [dateadd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) documentation:

> A string literal value must resolve to a datetime.

The [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) type can only accept milliseconds. Attempts to parse a string that has more accuracy than milliseconds will fail.

(Note that the `datetime` is rounded .000, .003, or .007 seconds. For example, 1 ms is rounded down to 0.)

The same error occurs if you try to declare a `datetime` and initialize it to a literal string that has more than 3 decimal places of second accuracy:

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime = '12:10:05.0000'
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

You can add to a `datetime2`, but you must declare the `datetime2` variable first instead of using a string literal:

```
declare @date datetime2 = '2021-11-01 05:10:00.0000000'
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @date)

2021-11-01 09:10:00.0000000
```