# Convert string to datetime in SQL, when Z and T literals are involved

Tags: sql, sql-server

A date is stored as string in the database:

```
2021-12-15T14:18:22.6496978Z
```

I try to convert it to datetime:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-12-15T14:18:22.6496978Z', 127)
```

using [127](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187928(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#arguments) which refers to `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ`, which I believe is the right style for the input date. But I am getting

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : DATEADD() not working beyond milliseconds when using a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69799263/sql-server-dateadd-not-working-beyond-milliseconds-when-using-a-string-value)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Use  DATETIME2 for  your precision `CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2021-12-15T14:18:22.6496978Z', 127)`

Comment: @jarlh microsoft sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATETIME` and `SMALLDATE` are legacy types(as in replaced-15-years-ago, don't-use legacy) that have a lot of quirks and limited precision. For example, `datetime` is only accurate to 0, 3 or 7 milliseconds. The value you tried to parse can't be converted to a `datetime` without losing precision.

The docs warn strongly against using this type, with a big pink warning at the top of the [DATETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) page:

> Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision. datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed applications.

In this case you need the `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` types introduced in 2005. Both types allow specifying a precision.

To preserve the timezone offset, use `datetimeoffset`.

```
select CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2021-12-15T14:18:22.6496978Z', 127)
----
2021-12-15 14:18:22.6496978 +00:00
```

To remove the offset, use `datetime2`. The result will have no assumed offset so you should take care to always treat it as UTC:

```
select CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2021-12-15T14:18:22.6496978Z', 127)
----
2021-12-15 14:18:22.6496978
```

In both cases you can specify the desired precision. For example, `datetime2(0)` will truncate fractional seconds:

```
select CONVERT(datetime2(0), '2021-12-15T14:18:22.6496978Z', 127)
---
2021-12-15 14:18:23
```